# Bar chart not drawing correctly

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I want to use the dc.js bar chart to draw the distribution of histbody temperature data (float number in text format like "35.3" in Celsius) from my csv file. I set the xUnits to precision 0.1, but when I draw the bar chart it seemed that all the input data were treated as integers but not floats. 
Totally no ideas about what went wrong here. I also tried the parseFloat function but it was still the same.

I am quite new to the d3,js and dc.js. Any suggestions or advice would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

this is part of my code...

```
    var groupname = "marker-select";
    var btpchart = dc.barChart("#btp",groupname);
    d3.csv("../static/data/all_body_temperature.csv", function(error, flights) {

        var formatNumber = d3.format(".3g");
        d.measure_time = parseDate(d.measure_time);

        flights.forEach(function(d, i) {
        d.measure_time = parseDate(d.measure_time);
        d.body_temperature = formatNumber(d.body_temperature);
        });

        var flight = crossfilter(flights),
        all = flight.groupAll(),
        body_temperature = flight.dimension(function(d) { return d.body_temperature; }),
        body_temperatures = body_temperature.group(Math.floor), 
        date = flight.dimension(function(d) { return d.measure_time; }),
        dates = date.group(d3.time.day),
        hour = flight.dimension(function(d) { return d.measure_time.getHours() + d.measure_time.getMinutes() / 60; }),
        hours = hour.group(Math.floor),

        btpchart
        .width(newWidth)
        .height(500)
        .margins({top: 30, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 40})
        .dimension(body_temperature)
        .group(body_temperatures)
        .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([32.0, 40.0]))
        .xUnits(dc.units.fp.precision(0.1))
        .elasticY(true);

        hourchart
        .width(newWidth)
        .height(500)
        .margins({top: 30, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 40})
        .dimension(hour)
        .group(hours)
        .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 24]))
        .elasticY(true);


        dc.renderAll(groupname);

    function parseDate(d) {
        return new Date(d);
    }


    });
```

Comment: You are grouping with the function `Math.floor` so your bins will be integers. Try taking out the `Math.floor`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just remove it and now it works like a charm!